# Android: File not found when opening raw resource when using GLSurfaceView

Tags: android

I have the following project structure....

[image]

However, when I run the following...

```
this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test);
```

I get the following...

> 06-03 13:40:38.614: E/Trace(9496): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

And when I run the following...

```
AssetFileDescriptor a = this.getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.test);
```

I get the following...

> 06-03 13:43:02.785: E/AndroidRuntime(9549): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.me.gl/com.me.gl.OpenGlActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/raw/test.bmp from drawable resource ID #0x7f040000
>
> 06-03 13:43:02.785: E/AndroidRuntime(9549): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed

Any ideas what I am missing??

**UPDATE**

Problem appears to be caused by the fact that the activity is using a GLSurfaceView. If I move before...

```
view = new GLSurfaceView(this);
```

I seem to have access to all resources. Changing the title a bit but can anyone give me an explanation why?

I will work on a test project later.

Comment: post more code and full stack trace. I don't see anything wrong so far.

Comment: I may delete this question, in the mean time I included more of the ST. I can see it says that the resource is compressed, however, I thought because it was in the raw folder it came uncompressed. Is this more of a limitation of the format (.bmp) I am using? Why does the 06-03 13:40:38.614: E/Trace(9496): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2) show up even without the second line

Comment: what is the size of the file?

Comment: 237,718  bytes (Additional char required by stack overflow)

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove the file extension ".bmp" from test.bmp file. Make sure it only shows filename test under raw folder. Hope this helps.

Comment: You don't need to remove the File Extensions. It works with it as well !